# Implicitly convert type 'int?' to 'int'

Tags: json, entity-framework, linq, webmethod

I try to get data in json format for this i try this web method code

Format:

```
[{name: 'May',data: [23]}, {name: 'June', data: [43]}, {name: 'July', data: [45]}]
```

Code:

```
try
{  
    var data = new Datas1().spsumdata().Select(s => new { name = s.Month, data = new int[] {s.data} }).ToArray();
    return Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.SerializeObject(data);
}
catch(Exception)
{
    throw new Exception();
}
```

but this shows an error:

> Cannot implicitly convert type 'int?' to 'int'. An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?)

When I add stored procedure in model and then create function import I select complex type

```
[EdmComplexTypeAttribute(NamespaceName="TrackDataModel", Name="spsumdata_Result")]
[DataContractAttribute(IsReference=true)]
[Serializable()]
public partial class spsumdata_Result : ComplexObject
{
    #region Simple Properties

    /// <summary>
    /// No Metadata Documentation available.
    /// </summary>
    [EdmScalarPropertyAttribute(EntityKeyProperty=false, IsNullable=true)]
    [DataMemberAttribute()]
    public global::System.String OwnerName
    {
        get
        {
            return _OwnerName;
        }
        set
        {
            OnOwnerNameChanging(value);
            ReportPropertyChanging("OwnerName");
            _OwnerName = StructuralObject.SetValidValue(value, true, "OwnerName");
            ReportPropertyChanged("OwnerName");
            OnOwnerNameChanged();
        }
    }
    private global::System.String _OwnerName;
    partial void OnOwnerNameChanging(global::System.String value);
    partial void OnOwnerNameChanged();

    /// <summary>
    /// No Metadata Documentation available.
    /// </summary>
    [EdmScalarPropertyAttribute(EntityKeyProperty=false, IsNullable=true)]
    [DataMemberAttribute()]
    public global::System.String Month
    {
        get
        {
            return _Month;
        }
        set
        {
            OnMonthChanging(value);
            ReportPropertyChanging("Month");
            _Month = StructuralObject.SetValidValue(value, true, "Month");
            ReportPropertyChanged("Month");
            OnMonthChanged();
        }
    }
    private global::System.String _Month;
    partial void OnMonthChanging(global::System.String value);
    partial void OnMonthChanged();

    /// <summary>
    /// No Metadata Documentation available.
    /// </summary>
    [EdmScalarPropertyAttribute(EntityKeyProperty=false, IsNullable=true)]
    [DataMemberAttribute()]
    public Nullable<global::System.Int32> data
    {
        get
        {
            return _data;
        }
        set
        {
            OndataChanging(value);
            ReportPropertyChanging("data");
            _data = StructuralObject.SetValidValue(value, "data");
            ReportPropertyChanged("data");
            OndataChanged();
        }
    }
    private Nullable<global::System.Int32> _data;
    partial void OndataChanging(Nullable<global::System.Int32> value);
    partial void OndataChanged();

    #endregion
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `data` property is of type `int?` but you're attempting to add it to an array of type `int`.

You need to either make the array of type `int?` to match or convert the `data` value to `int`.

```
var data = new Datas1().spsumdata()
    .Select(s => new
    {
        name = s.Month,
        // take your pick
        //data = new int?[] { s.data },
        //data = new int[] { s.data ?? 0 },
        //data = new int[] { s.data.Value },
    }).ToArray();
```

Answer (score 0):

> Cannot implicitly convert type 'int?' to 'int'.

`'int?'` it mean that support `integer` and `null` value, if you want to convert it into integer.

```
A = B??0;
```

where `A` as `int` and `B` as `int?`

```
B??0
```

it mean that when `B` contain `null` vale it convert into `0` value.